# Creating a student arraylist to add students to course class Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Im trying to create a student arraylist to a a course class so that when a student is added the arraylist is increases. this is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Saj
 */
public class Course {
    private String courseName;
    private int noOfStudents;
    private String teacher;
    public static int instances = 0;

    //Getters
    public String getCourseName(){
        return this.courseName;
    }
    public int getNoOfStudents(){
        return this.noOfStudents;
    }
    public String getTeacher(){
        return this.teacher;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setCourseName(String courseName){
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
    public void setNoOfStudents(int noOfStudents){
        this.noOfStudents = noOfStudents;
    }
    public void setTeacher(String teacher){
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor. Populates course name, number of students with defaults
     */
    public Course(){
        instances++;
        this.noOfStudents = 0;
        this.courseName = "Not Set";
        this.teacher = "Not Set";
    }

    /** 
     * Constructor with parameters 
     * @param noOfStudents integer
     * @param courseName String with the Course name
     * @param teacher String with the teacher
    */
    public Course(int noOfStudents, String courseName, String teacher){
        this.noOfStudents = noOfStudents;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

}
```

Im unsure how to implement the array list. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: "Im unsure how to implement the array list." You do not implement the ArrayList. It's a built-in collection. Declare it as follows `List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();`. That is assuming you actually have created the Student class.

Comment: Have you read the documentation and/or looked at any tutorials/guides about `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Arqan where do I declare it?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's a bunch of code, I have no idea what to do next, please hold my hand and guide me"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 2):

With a little bit of research you can find many tutorials to achieve what you intend, but i'll try to set you in the right path just so you have an answear and somewhere to start.

1. What is a Student ? 
   Is it a String containing just a name, is it an object that represents a student that can have some properties ?
   One example is

   ```
   public class Student{
       private int number;
       private String name;
       private int age;
       // Basically anything that makes sense for a student.

       public Student(int number, String name, int age){
           this.number = number;
           this.name = name;
           this.age = age;
       }

       // .... Getters and Setters.
   }
   ```
2. You need some place to store every Student added to the course, that is what the ArrayList is for i.e

   ```
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Student foo = new Student(23, "Foo", 22);
    students.add(foo); // This is how you add to a List (in this case a List of Student objects and more precisely an ArrayList of Students).
   ```

You will need to keep the list in your course class as an instance variable, and add a method in wich you can pass a student and inside the method all you have to is add to your list of students, you may even do some validation if you want.

If you have more doubts first search for a solution before asking questions that can easily be found.
Here are some references:

[Java List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

[Java ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

**EDIT** the way you are adding your students is almost done but you have an error and also your list of students only resides inside the constructor, wich means you cannot use the list for saving students outside.

Below is the correct code

```
/** 
 * Constructor with parameters 
 * @param noOfStudents integer
 * @param courseName String with the Course name
 * @param teacher String with the teacher
*/
public Course(int noOfStudents, String courseName, String teacher){
    this.studentList = new ArrayList<Student>(); // The declaration is in above in your class, as an instance variable.
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.teacher = teacher;
}
 ArrayList<Student> studentList; // You can move this so it sits above besides your other variables, but it will also work like this.
public boolean addStudent(Student student){
    if (student==null || studentList.contains(student)) { // You had Student.contains, wich will give an error because Student (class) doesnt have a static method named contains.
        return false;
    }
    studentList.add(student); // you had the same problem here, you had Student.add(student), wich is wrong and it would not compile.
    return true;
}
```

**Be sure that you have created the Student class and it is without any errors.**

**Tested and working code, change it to fullfill your needs more precisely**

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Course {
    private String courseName;
    private int noOfStudents;
    private String teacher;
    public static int instances = 0;
private ArrayList<Student> studentList;

    //Getters
    public String getCourseName(){
        return this.courseName;
    }
    public int getNoOfStudents(){
        return this.noOfStudents;
    }
    public String getTeacher(){
        return this.teacher;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setCourseName(String courseName){
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
    public void setNoOfStudents(int noOfStudents){
        this.noOfStudents = noOfStudents;
    }
    public void setTeacher(String teacher){
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor. Populates course name, number of students with defaults
     */
    public Course(){
        instances++;
        this.noOfStudents = 0;
        this.courseName = "Not Set";
        this.teacher = "Not Set";
    }

    /** 
     * Constructor with parameters 
     * @param noOfStudents integer
     * @param courseName String with the Course name
     * @param teacher String with the teacher
    */
    public Course(int noOfStudents, String courseName, String teacher){
        this.studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public boolean addStudent(Student student){
        if (student==null || studentList.contains(student)) {
            return false;
        }
        studentList.add(student);
        return true;
    }

    public void printStudents(){
    for(Student s : studentList)
            System.out.println(s.getName() + ", with " + s.getAge() + " year(s)");
    }

public static class Student{
        private int number;
        private String name;
        private int age;
        // Basically anything that makes sense for a student.

        public Student(int number, String name, int age){
            this.number = number;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        // .... Getters and Setters.

        public int getNumber(){ 
            return this.number;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }

        public int getAge(){
            return this.age;
        }
}
    // Testing code
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Course oop = new Course(6, "Object Oriented Programming", "LeBron James");
        oop.addStudent(new Course.Student(6, "Michael Jordan", 56));
        oop.addStudent(new Course.Student(23, "Kyrie Irving", 24));
        oop.addStudent(new Course.Student(14, "Kevin Love", 27));
        System.out.println(oop.getCourseName() + " has the following students");
        oop.printStudents();

    }

}
```

Comment: See the answer that I have posted with the tweaked code but I am getting an error.

Comment: @donk2017 See my edit, i have corrected some things with your code, you had some serious problems with it.

Comment: I have to use the toString and  then do `System.out.println(course.toString());` and `System.out.println(student.toString());` from main class to print out the course and student information. Also I have to enter student details from the terminal when the code is run.

Answer (score 0):

Just add attribute to your class

```
List<Student> students;
```

In constructors, initialize this list:

```
students = new ArrayList<>();
```

Create method to add student to list:

```
public boolean addStudent(Student stud) {
     if (stud == null || students.contains(stud)) {
        return false;
     }
     students.add(stud);
     return true;
}
```

Also check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html for documentation of list.
Question is, do you want to add students in constructor? If so, add parameter to your constructor

```
public Course(int noOfStudents, String courseName,
              String teacher, List<Student> students){
    this.noOfStudents = noOfStudents;
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.teacher = teacher;
    this.students = new Arraylist<>(students);
}
```

Comment: See the answer that I have posted with the tweaked code but I am getting an error.

Comment: What error do you get?
And where have you declared List<Student> attribute?

add it right after  `public static int instances = 0;`
just type private `List<Student> students;`

+ One tip, don't use 
`ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();`
use `List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();` instead